# how to add class into last li of first level

Tags: jquery

How do I add a class to the last LI on the 1st level (that means beside class second)
`$('#navtop li:last').addClass('last')` adds the class into the last li of last level

```
<div id="navtop">
<ul>
    <li class="first">
        <a href="#"><b>About</b></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about/service-area/"><b>Service Area</b></a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#about/board-of-directors/"><b>Board of Directors</b></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                    <li><a href="#about/board-of-directors/contact-board-of-directors/"><b>Contact Board of Directors</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about/board-of-directors/contact-board-of-directors/"><b>Contact Board of Directors</b></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="second">
        <a href="#"><b>About</b></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about/service-area/"><b>Service Area</b></a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#about/board-of-directors/"><b>Board of Directors</b></a>
                <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
                    <li><a href="#about/board-of-directors/contact-board-of-directors/"><b>Contact Board of Directors</b></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about/board-of-directors/contact-board-of-directors/"><b>Contact Board of Directors</b></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parent > child selector - http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

```
$('#navtop>li:last').addClass('last')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking how to put the class into the last li of .first

```
$('#navtop .first li:last').addClass('last');
```

If you're asking how to put the class into the last li of each one (first, second, etc)

```
$('#navtop>ul>li li:last').addClass('last');
```