# Add class into last li of first level

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

i'm working on styling my site's main menu and i would like to add a class to the first and last LI elements in the unordered list, but **only** the first and last items in the top level.

```
<div id="primary-menu-container" class="menu">
    <div id="menu-icon">Menu</div>
    <ul id="primary-menu" class="hover sf-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Fabrics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contemporary</a></li>
        <li><a href="#>Vinyl</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gold</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test Tag</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Testing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">news</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>​
```

the first one is pretty easy since the first li is always a top-level list element.  i'm confused about targeting the last one since there could be a sub-menu on the last top-level list element.

there was no solution selected, but per some of the responses at : [how to add class into last li of first level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515847/how-to-add-class-into-last-li-of-first-level)

i've tried the following, which works on the first item, but adds the "last" class to "Test Tag" and all its children, whereas I only want this class added to the "Test Tag" li.

```
$​("#primary-menu > li:first").addClass("first");
$("#primary-menu > li:last").addClass("last");
```

here's my fiddle.  ​

http://jsfiddle.net/tdcf7/1/

Comment: Note that you don't need JS for this if you're targeting modern browsers. Simply create CSS such as this: `#primary-menu > li:last-child > a { ... }`; see [`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) and [`:last-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#last-child-pseudo).

Comment: For example: http://jsfiddle.net/tdcf7/5/

Comment: ahh.. good to know.  thanks!  old IE can go jump off a bridge as far as i am concerned.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/tdcf7/3/

```css
.last > a{ color: red }
```

It was not adding the class to all descendants; your CSS selector (`.last a`) was just selecting all descendants of the single item with the class.

By using the child selector instead of descendant, the fix above only selects the `<a>` that is directly a child of the `<li>` with that class.

Alternatively--if it is hard to select exactly just the contents you want--you can always apply styling to all descendants and then override it for the incorrect ones:

```css
li           { color:green } /* default style            */
li.last *    { color:red   } /* hit 'em all!             */
li.last ul * { color:green } /* ooh...but not these ones */
```

Comment: Place the relevant code here please, not just a link to the fiddle.

Comment: @Gabe Always. What you saw was 30s of the bad habit of getting a bit of an answer up first before expanding. Rep wars! :p

Comment: Fair enough, just wanted to help the cause :)

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is fine, it's your CSS that is making the sub-list red as well.

```
.last > a{ color: red;}
```

The `>` will cause it to only affect direct descendants

Comment: since you both gave the same, correct answer I gave I accepted Phrogz' solution since he was a bit quicker on the draw.  thank you for taking the time to answer though!